# Bi-directional Parameter issue in Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have two task in hand to achieve in a single report.

1. Application URL filtering - One ListID will be passed in the URL to filter the report. I achieved this by having @id as parameter for my datasets. In this scenario I only had one parameter in place.
2. Reporting Server filtering - For users who don't have access to application/db, they can go to the Reporting server and Select a 'ListName' from a dropdown parameter(@ListName) that fills the List ID parameter.
   I achieved this scenario by cascading parameters and having two datasets one for independent dropdown parameter(ListName) another for dependent parameter(ListID).

But since I cannot filter the report based on ListName from the application, I need a way to achieve both in the same report. When I try to filter the report using '?id=123' from application URL it does not filter the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two parameters, you are only ever need to filter on ListID so this is the only parameter you need. You only use ListName to look up the ListID.

Let's say your dataset for the list parameter values looks like this:

```
SELECT ListID, ListName FROM Lists
```

Link this Dataset to your ListID parameter's Available Values.

Parameter objects have a `Value` property which is used to run the query and the `Label` property which is display the list names to the user. Map ListID to the Value and ListName to the Label.

Now the application can simply provide a list id to the report. However, when a user runs the report, they will see the list names. When they select one, the corresponding ListID will be provided as the report parameter Value.

Comment: I tried setting the Available values for id from a similar result set and providing ListName as the label value. But it doesn't filter on using the URL '?id=123'. We want to pass only the id field in the url. The problem is that by allowing the Available values I have to use a dataset that is unfiltered with id parameter. The URL filter works fine when I use a dataset such as SELECT ListID, ListName FROM Lists where ListID = @id. But here I am not able to provide a dropdown since it doesn't allow using Available values/Default values for the parameter.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a query with all the list ids that you want to be able to select from for the Available Values, so use a separate query from the one you use to run the report. You will only be able to select ids that appear in the query's list of available values so all valid ids must be returned by the query in order to be able to select them. If you use a select query with `where ListID = @id` then you won't be able to select any ids because you have not entered the @id parameter yet so there aren't any ids in the list to select from.